# Rotate Big Table

Tags: tables, tabularx, rotating, sidewaystable

My rotated table cannot be compiled. I could compile it before but something changed. When I could compile it the columns did not align like they should. I already tried different table environments but I cannot find a solution. Every help would be very much appreciated.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}
\begin{sidewaystable}

\hline
\multicolumn{4}{c}{None (N)} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Mild (M)} &        \multicolumn{4}{c}{Moderate (M)} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Severe (S)} \\ 
 \multicolumn{4}{c}{Prevalence in \% (95\% CI)}& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Prevalence in \% (95\% CI)}& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Prevalence in \% (95\% CI)} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{(Prevalence in \% (95\% CI)} \\
& Ger & Mig 1 & Mig 2 & Ref & Ger & Mig 1 & Mig 2 & Ref& Ger & Mig 1 & Mig 2 & Ref& Ger & Mig 1 & Mig 2 & Ref\\
\hline

\textbf{Gender} & &  & \\
Male& 64 (60 - 67) &19 (16 - 22) & 9 (7 - 11) & 9 (6 - 11)   \\
Female& 48 (43 - 54) & 22 (18 - 27)  & 12 (9 - 16) & 17 (0.12 - 0.22) \\

\textbf{XXX} &  & & &  \\
\hspace*{5mm}  18-24& 63 (57 - 69) & 21 (15 - 26) & 8 (5 - 11)& 9 (5 - 0.13)  \\ 
\hspace*{5mm}  25-34& 65 (61 - 70) & 17 (13 - 20)& 11 (7 - 15) & 7 (4 -  9)  \\
\hspace*{5mm}  35-44& 57 (51 - 63) & 20 (15 - 25) & 8 (5 - 11) & 15 (10 - 20)  \\
\hspace*{5mm}  45-54& 43 (34 - 53) & 18 (11 - 25) & 11 (7 - 16) & 27 (17 - 37)  \\
\hspace*{5mm}  $\geq$ 55 & 29 (16 - 41) & 46 (29 - 64)& 13 (4 - 23) & 12 (0 - 24)  \\ 

   \textbf{Level of XXXXXXX}    & &  & & \\



----------


\hspace*{5mm} Low& 59 (55 - 64)  & 19 (15 - 23)   & 9  (7 - 11)  & 13 (9 - 16)\\ 
        \hspace*{5mm} Medium& 61 (55 - 68)  & 21 (15 - 26)  & 8 (4 - 12)  & 10  (6 - 14) \\
    \hspace*{5mm} High& 63 (56 - 70)  & 19 (14 - 25)  & 12  (7 - 17) &  6 (3 - 10)\\
    \hline


    \end{sidewaystable}

    \end{tabularx}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: It is `tabularx` which should be nested in `sidewaystable`, not the converse.

Comment: The desired width and column specifiers are also missing. Apart from that, I also think, that a `&` is missing before your first `\multicolumn{4}{c}` command of the first and second row.

Comment: Additionally, if your other three sets of four columns contain similar amounts of numbers as the first set, your table will be much too wide to fit onto the page (even with an extremely small font size).

Comment: Is this issue solved? How?